# What happens in a ARM based system before the OS is loaded?

Tags: boot, operating-systems, arm

What happens in a ARM based system before the OS is loaded and do they have BIOS, drivers, MBR or a different approach instead of these?

Comment: "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139952/what-is-the-booting-process-for-arm .